# PostgreSQL login: is the password sent over SSL?

Tags: postgresql, ssl

When I configure my PostgreSQL server to use SSL
and connect remotely, with the PostgreSQL client `psql`,
and specify a password,
will the password be sent over SSL?
Or is the SSL connection established after the password has been verified?

Here is how I connect:
(note that the `SSL connection` info message isn't displayed until after I've logged in)

```
-bash-4.1$ psql --host myserver.mysite.com Database Username
Password for user Username: 
psql (9.1.1)
SSL connection (cipher: DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits: 256)
Type "help" for help.

Database=>
```

(I think the password is double md5 salted and encrypted but SSL would make me feel better.)

Comment: You know that SSL only protects against MITM attacks, right?

Comment: You can use a network sniffer to trivially check this...

Comment: @MДΓΓ БДLL I have my databases and backup databases and appservers in different datacenters and countries so MITM attacks are of relevance

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL -- I didn't understand why you asked about MITM attacks -- did you have some other particular attack in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the entire session is using SSL, including login/password info.  You can easily verify this with tcpdump.

Comment: (Okay, thanks for testing.   --  I suppose that certainly this behavior won't be changed in the future)